# Lock Y-axis scrolling in horizontal RecyclerView when swiping on x-axis

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to disable the scroll on one axis in a recycler view if you are swiping on the other axis? Currently I have a recylerview that's supposed to swipe horizontally (x axis) but if your swipe has even a hint of diagonal movement it will also scroll the screen on the y axis which can eventually obscure the view of the recycler

Comment: you can use the Horizontal layout manager in setlayoutmanager() method it scrolls only horizontal.

Comment: here is the code:

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

Comment: This is what I already have. I still have vertical scrolling while swiping horizontally.

Comment: make sure that your recycler view widget in XML is not in NestedScrollView

Comment: It's currently in a ScrollView and a LinearLayout, in that order.

Comment: remove the scroll view if you cannot remove scroll view then update in NestedScroll view

Comment: Is there something additional I would have to do to fix this in a NestedScrollView?

Comment: In NestedScrollView, All widget scroll stops. only scroll the size of the widget if your recycler view in NestedScrollView then it does not scroll vertical but it scrolls only horizontal